# swarm simulation

Tags: ros, simulator-stage, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can anyone point me to any stack which simulates a swarm of robots on stage or gazebo and implements any formation behavior or clustering behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38879/swarm-simulation/) by [iceman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2843/iceman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@iceman Have a look here - http://answers.ros.org/question/11192/swarm-robotics-facility-in-ros/

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0